# How can I calculate the speed of a rotation unity 3d c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

so the thing is: i have a sensor that makes a rigidbody rotate, the problem is that i can't calculate the speed in which it was rotated (If the sensor was moved fast the object would also move fast but when it collides with another gameobject it won't apply the speed/force which with it has been rotated)
Is there any way I can calculate the speed/force in which it has recently rotated so that i can apply that speed/force to another object when it collides?

note: im not entirely sure if what i need is speed or force

```
float rot = float.Parse (sp.ReadLine());
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 90, rot);
```

note: because of how the object was designed it has to be rotated by default in 90 degrees. Basically what im doing is receiving information from a Gyroscope and puting it in the object rotation.

The sensor gives values from -90 to 90 in the form of Float, when it is rotated to the left it gives values from -90 to 0, when rotated to the right it gives values from 0 to 90. this values should be used to graphically rotate the object and also aply the speed in which it was rotated when it collides whith another gameobject (if it was moved fast from -90 to -20 for example it should apply more force than if it was moved slowly from -90 to -50 to -20)

Comment: You shouldn't be setting rotation directly if you want accurate physical interactions - you should consider using the physics system and applying torque to the object, of a magnitude based on how much/fast your sensor has moved.

Comment: Im not entirely sure if i understand you, can you give me a code example of what you say?

Comment: I'm going to need you to show your current approach, so me and other members have a better idea of what data you're getting from the sensor and how you're using it. Please edit your question to include the relevant code, and we'll see if it can be adapted to work as you require.

Comment: there i edited it, please tell me if you need more information, thank you for your help :)

Comment: All right - let me know if there's anything unclear about the answer I supplied, and if it adequately meets your needs in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to cause believable physical interaction between objects, you never want to manipulate the `transform` directly. Instead, you should be making use of the various methods available to physically influence an attached `Rigidbody`.

To apply rotation in this case, you're going to want to use [`Rigidbody.AddTorque()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque.html). Here's an idea of how you might use it:

```
// Probably get this value in Start() and save it for later
Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

float rot = float.Parse (sp.ReadLine());

// transform.forward is the unit vector corresponding to the local z-axis of the object
Vector3 rotationAxis = transform.forward * rot;
rb.AddTorque(rotationAxis);
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I can see that your aproach might be extremely usefull, since it is solving another issue that i had. but there is stil a problem: the sensor is constantly sending values to unity,therefore if i use this code, the gameobject will be continously moving and adding force, which isn't what i need. 
another issue is that the sensor also sends negative values (it sends values from -90 to 90), so im not sure how the torque will work with a negative value.

Comment: in addition, the gameobject should be able to rotate backwards and forwards, calculating the speed in both directions. (the game object can colide with another object from both sides) so i have to apply the force in both sides and im not entirely sure of how that may work

Comment: @KevinDaich What exactly is the nature of this sensor? What kind of data can be expected from it? I think a couple edits to your question may be necessary, so it's easier to determine how to process the data coming from it into a usable form.

Comment: there i edited it, let me know if you need more info

Comment: is there a way in which i can work with both, the way i was already working and mixing it with torque? (using my old way to rotate de object visually and using torque to apply force but not moving the object) cause that may solve the problem but im not sure if it can be done

Comment: @KevinDaich Hmmm. You could try the Rigidbody equivalent with [`Rigidbody.MoveRotation()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html), though you may still end up with rather strange physical interactions during quick movements.

Comment: im not sure how to apply Rigidbody.MoveRotation() to my current code

Comment: @KevinDaich You'd just retrieve the attached Rigidbody like I did in my example, then call the method, passing in the quaternion version of your Vector3 rotation. The docs show you how to do the conversion.